# Where can I find information on old Kontron emulators?

Tags: hardware, programming, emulation

Way back in the mid-80s, I worked as a programmer for the Apple II family, Commodore and Atari machines. I remember programming them using a big intimidating box branded Kontron stacked on top of my IBM PC/AT. On the back of the unit, it interfaced to the 6502 machine, the target, and a host PC via ribbon cables.

From the host, I could execute my code on the target machine and halt via a keystroke or a set breakpoint and see the contents of its memory and registers. It was very responsive and gave me complete control over the device. I was spoiled rotten by the time I left for a job programming the Atari at another company. It was then excruciatingly painful working off floppies, 40-column text and only 64K of RAM.

If this box sounds familiar, is there any info on it? I don't know what it was supposed to be called, but we called it an emulator.

Comment: These things are also called "in-circuit emulator" (ICE). Kontron sold lots of things, and googling finds [a comment](https://hackaday.com/2021/10/15/heres-a-100-mhz-pin-compatible-6502-replacement/) on hackaday that Kontron had those things (and they were really expensive), but nothing much else. Kontron still exists and [has a webpage](https://www.kontron.com/), maybe you can contact them, and they have something in their archives?

Comment: Bitsavers has a "Slave Emulator Hardware Reference Manual" from 1982 available: http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/futuredata/2302/2302-5003-01_Slave_Emulator_Hardware_Reference_Manual_Oct82.pdf that looks likely.

Comment: I worked on a Kontron KDS for a good few years in the mid-80's,, a CP/M system with a Z80, 256 KB RAM and a 5 GB HDD. Great to use and very solidly built. Didn't have any ICEs though, they were shatteringly expensive and the KDS and assemblers wasn't cheap to start with.

Comment: @JonCuster I found that manual, but it's specifically NOT for in-circuit emulation, instead it completely emulates the target system (that's what the "slave" refers to).

Comment: Thanks. It's been so long. I do remember CP/M was part of it. The "emulator" wasn't really an emulator because it actually controlled the target at the hardware level, allowing you to stop and observe memory.

Comment: @dirkt, Not sure if this is the exact model, but definitely familiar. In the manual, it says:

"The Emulator substitutes an identical processor for the target system's processor. To eliminate critical physical distances, this Emulation Processor is housed in a sm~ll portable chassis called a Probe, which is connected by a short cable to the target system's vacant microprocessor socket."

It only emulates the processor, not the entire target system.

Comment: Looking at the diagrams, the system I used only had the slave emulator without the console. This may have been an earlier model or the same model and the console was optional. 

Anyway, thanks!  I still can't afford one. LOL!!

Comment: Say, are ICEs themselves on topic here? I'd now like to ask a question about how those things were _built_, back in the days before FPGAs and ASICs.

Comment: @davidbak, definitely on-topic. ICEs played an important part in building old computers. If questions about developing their ROMs in assembler and so on for those machines are on-topic, so should ICEs be.